# Send response after call back functions execution completion in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a problem with call back functions and loops in nodejs how can I do so that the response should be send after the call back functions execution completion

```
app.post('/data', function(req,res){
 var send = []
 for (var i =0; i < p_objReq.body.quantity; i++) {
   Instruments.count({//condetion}, function(err, count){
     //using count and other parameters I am generating the code which is unique
      Instruments.find({id: 'rondom_generated_code'},function(err, instrumentsCount){
         if(instrumentsCount.length == 0){
           send.push(rondom_generated_code)
           if(send.length == p_objReq.body.quantity)
             p_objRes.json({success : true, data : send})
         }
         else{
            Instruments.count({//condetion}, function(err, count){
              //using count and other parameters I am generating the code which is unique
             send.push(rondom_generated_code)
             if(send.length == p_objReq.body.quantity)
               p_objRes.json({success : true, data : send})
            })
         }
      })
   })
 }
})
```

when i wrote like this its sending the same random code that is last generated one. I tried removing the whole thing and written in function and called back but its also not working

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [`Q.js`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which is one of `Promise` library. More APIs of `Q.js`, please refer to the link in it. Here is one sample codes may could help you, If I catch you correctly for your question.

```
var Promise = require('Q');

app.post('/data', function(req,res){
    var send = [];
    var p = function () {
        var deferred = Q.defer();

        Instruments.count({condetion}, function(err, count){
           //using count and other parameters I am generating the code which is unique
            if (err) {
                deferred.reject(new Error(error));
            } else {
                send.push(randomnumber)
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var ps = [];
    for (var i =0; i < p_objReq.body.quantity; i++) {
        ps.push(p);  
    }

    Q.all(ps).then(function(){ res.json({success : true, data : send}); });
});
```